# как подключить функцию к компоненту react?

Tags: reactjs

мне нужно обратиться к элементу  и навесить на него обработчик событий, не понимаю как это сделать...

```js
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'

export default class Scenes_5_20 extends React.Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <Fragment>
            // элемент, к которому нужно обратиться
                <a-video src="assets/video/approach.mp4" position="-0.5 0 -5" width="4" height="2"></a-video>
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

// функция, которую нужно выполнить
var video = document.getElementById("video");

var pausing_function = function () {
    if (this.currentTime >= 10) {
        this.pause();
        this.removeEventListener("timeupdate", pausing_function);
    }
};

video.addEventListener("timeupdate", pausing_function);
```

Comment: вы можете повесить событие с помощью свойства onClick

Comment: можно поставить `<a-video ref={setup}`, где `function setup(element){...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `componentDidMount`, см. пример ниже.
Заменил ваш компонент `a-video` на `video` для наглядности.

```js
class Scenes_5_20 extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const video = document.getElementById("video");
    const pausing_function = ({target}) => {
      if (target.currentTime > 10) {
        target.pause();
        video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", pausing_function);
      }
      console.log(target.currentTime)
    };
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", pausing_function);
  }
  
  render() {

    return ( <React.Fragment >
      <video src = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"
      id = "video"
      controls />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Scenes_5_20 / > , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```